# Cursor is moving too slowly in Xcode

Tags: macos, xcode4.3

I' using XCode 4.3.2. Moving the caret is so slow that it's forcing me to use the mouse when I need to reach a given location on the screen.

Other applications behave normally. Keyboard sensitivity is set to the maximum speed. In XCode, it takes 10 seconds to go down 70 lines; in TextEdit, it takes 2.5 seconds.

It looks like it is related to the contextual help.

Is it a known problem in XCode, and is there a way to solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens where there are too many open projects in XCode.